# how to login to another user with its enviroment on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, sudo

On Ubuntu, when I open a terminal, it's logged in via my own user. I want to loging as user 'jenkins' and use its own environment setup, i.e. home dir etc. Also, I don't have the password for 'jenkins', so all the 'su' solutions don't work for me.

Comment: connect as root then `su jenkins`.

Answer (score 2):

`su` is short for **switch user**.

With `su jenkins` you become user jenkins, but don't execute his profile scripts.
Calling `su - jenkins` or `su -l jenkins` does the same, but also executes his profile scripts.

See also the [su manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html).

In case you don't have the password for user jenkins (or don't want to login with password), but are allowed to call "sudo" you can also add "sudo" in front of the su (i.e. `sudo su - jenkins` )

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo su -l jenkins`

You'll have the env as you logged in directly to Jenkins.